# Prove $\left<H\cup K\right>=H\lor K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given the following definitions

**Joint of 2 subgroups**

$$
\begin{split}
H \lor K
 &= \{h_1k_1h_2k_2....h_nk_n  | h_i \in H, k_i \in K, n\in\mathbb{N_0}\} \\
 &= \left\{\left. \prod\limits_{i=1}^n h_ik_i \right| h_i \in H, k_i \in K,n \in \mathbb{N_0}\right\}
\end{split}
$$

**Subgroup generated by a set**
Let $A\subseteq G$ and $G$ be a group. We let
$$\left<A\right> = \bigcap_{A\subseteq L\leq G}L$$

**Using these definitions I must prove $\left<H\cup K\right>=H\lor K$**

***My try:***
I try to prove the double inclusion

i) $H\lor K\subseteq  \langle H\cup K\rangle$

I take an $x \in H \lor K$, so $x=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}h_ik_i $
and I suppose by absurd that $x \notin \langle H\cup K\rangle = \bigcap_{A\subseteq L_j\leq G}L_j$ with  $A=H\cup K$

Then $\exists j_0 $ such that $x \notin L_{j_0} \supseteq H\cup K $

Then $x \notin H\cup K $  $\Rightarrow $$x \notin H$ and $x \notin K$

... and I don't know how to continue( in case this is the right way)

ii) $\left<H\cup K\right>\subseteq H\lor K$

I take $x \in \langle H\cup K\rangle=\bigcap_{(H\cup K)\subseteq L_j<G}L_j \Rightarrow x \in L_j  $   $   \forall  j$

...same here I don't know how to continue

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: I think I would prove a lemma: that $\langle A \rangle$ is the set of products of elements of $A$ and inverses of elements of $A$.

Comment: You are proceeding backwards in each case. To show $H\vee K\subseteq \langle H\cup K\rangle$, you need to take something in $H\vee K$ and show it is in $\langle H\cup K\rangle$, not the other way around.

Comment: I think my proof would consist of the building blocks: if $A$ is a subgroup such that $H \subseteq A$ and $K \subseteq A$, then $H \vee K \subseteq A$.  $H \vee K$ is a subgroup, and $H \subseteq H \vee K$, $K \subseteq H \vee K$.  If $A$ is a subgroup such that $S \subseteq A$, then $\langle S \rangle \subseteq A$.  $\langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup, and $S \subseteq \langle S \rangle$.

Comment: To show something in $H\vee K$ must lie in $\langle H\cup K\rangle$, take $x\in H\vee K$, and use its expression as a product to show that it lies in every subgroup of $G$ that contains both $H$ and $K$. To show that $\langle H\cup K\rangle\subseteq H\vee K$, show that $H\vee K$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $H\cup K$, and conclude from the definition of $\langle H\cup K\rangle$ that it must be contained in $H\vee K$.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin that was I typo thank you. I am going forward and in the first case I was trying to use the absurd, negating the thesis

Comment: @Arturo Magidin  how do I use the expression as a product of $x$ to show that it lies in every subgroup of G that contains both H and K?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Last I checked, any subgroup must contain all products of elements it contains.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prove the containments by contradiction.
Moreover, in order to *explicitly* exhibit the containments, one would need a direct description of $\langle H\cup K\rangle$, which is just the aim of this exercise!

Clearly, $H\cup K\subseteq H\lor K$. 
Prove that $H\lor K$ is a subgroup, and whenever a subgroup $S$ contains $H\cup K$, we have $H\lor K\subseteq S$.

> For the second part: if $S\le G$ and $H\cup K\subseteq S$, then each element $h_1k_1\dots h_nk_n$ of $H\lor K$ is also an element of $S$, since it's closed under the group operation.
>  This proves that $H\lor K$ is the intersection of all such subgroups $S$.

Comment: I have already proved that both $<A>$ and $H \lor K$ are subgroups and also a nearly tautological proof of what I am asking using what you suggested fo the second case, that $H\lor K $being the smallest subgroup containing H and K must be inside any other subgroup  The purpose is to prove it by explicitly using the given definitions

Comment: If you know $H\lor K$ is a subgroup, and $H\cup K \subseteq H\lor K$, then the inclusion holds for their generated subgroups, proving one direction. The other containment follows by definition of 'generated subgroup'. In order to explicitly exhibit the containments, one would need a direct description of $\langle H\cup K\rangle$ which is just the aim of this exercise.

Comment: For the first containment, would the generated subgroup oh $H\lor K$ coincide with itself?, how to prove it? and for the second, how does the containment follows from the definition of generated subgroup?

Comment: If $S$ is a subgroup, then $S$ is the intersection of all subgroups that contain $S$, so its generated subgroup is itself. For the second, I think I wrote a mistake in my previous comment. Rather follow the hint of my answer.